# Odd behavior with unordered-containers (HashMap.Strict)?

Tags: haskell, unordered-map

sorry for the nebulous question, but has anyone observed buggy behaviors 
with `Data.HashMap.Strict` from `unordered-containers-0.2.3.0` on GHC 7.6.3?

In particular, there are Maps which clearly contain a key `k` but `lookup` 
fails (returns `Nothing`). (I know the key is *in* the Map because printing 
out the results of `toList` shows the key in the output.

I've seen this across two different code bases now. Does anyone know if this 
is a known issue with 0.2.3.0 ? Perhaps I should upgrade?

Otherwise, I will put in the time to find a minimal test that shows the glitch.

(Also, if I should ask this elsewhere, please let me know...)

Thanks!

Ranjit.

Comment: It is not enough to see the printed output, one should make sure a linear search through `toList` succeeds. Printing can hide differences.

Comment: What is the key type and does it implement `Eq`?

Comment: You could try to see if issues disapper with `hashable` < 1.2. I often see all kinds of weird behaviour with recent `hashable`

Comment: Good point, will add the explicit search through `toList`! (Still, am pretty sure its a bug.) The key type is a `newtype` wrapper around `String`. The key does implement `Eq`. Will try with < 1.2. Thanks!

Comment: Just tried the explicit search `elem x $ fst <$> toList m` and it returns `True` so, pretty sure there's something odd...

Comment: @MatveyAksenov you are right! adding a < 1.2 constraint made the issue go away... thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like [#66](https://github.com/tibbe/hashable/issues/66).

You can try building `HEAD` with `-f-sse2` and see if it helps.
(Note that it doesn't have a proper fix yet, only a workaround.)

If you have simple code to show the problem, please add it to the issue.

Comment: I will try to extract a small code sample over the weekend, and add it to the issue. Thanks!